# How to display an image on any computer using Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to display the image on any computer that opens the program .. But the software shows the picture only that the image and the software are in the same place (I want the image to be inside the software)
And if it is not in the same place then it shows me this error: (image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDAyD.png

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("d.png");
    namedWindow("Image");
    imshow("Image", img);
    waitKey(0);
    cout << "h";
    int i;
    cin >> i;
}
```

Comment: It is easy, just put your image in the project `resources` folder and DONE.

Comment: i add new existing (image) to "Resourses File" and i have this Error
```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD5F17A388 in OpenCv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000BA648FF3C0
```

Comment: @ BahramdunAdil ???

Comment: You should first know how to read resource file in C++, indeed it is not OpenCV exception, it belongs to C++, so you try to learn how to read the resource file in C++, then when you done, you should read the image as a byte array, then give this byte array to OpenCV to convert it to image.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write a program that converts the image to a string of the form `std::vector<uint8_t> image{ 0x01, 0x02 ... };` list each byte. Then save that string in a file.

Then `#include` that file into your program and read the image data from the `image` variable.

This way the image will be embedded in your executable by the compiler.

Comment: Do you know a guide that explains how to do it? Or is there perhaps another more simple way to do this?

Comment: @Progremmer3 What do you need to know? A program to read the image file and dump it out as a comma separated list of byte values should take 10min to write and be ~20 lines of code. Then you are done.

Comment: @Progremmer3 or you can use `gimp` which can save as `c` code :)